# TypeError: brain.NeuralNetwork is not a constructor

Tags: node.js, machine-learning

I am new to Machine Learning.

Having followed the steps in this simple [Maching Learning](https://codingthesmartway.com/beginners-guide-to-neural-networks-in-javascript-with-brain-js/) using the Brain.js library, it beats my understanding why I keep getting the error message below:

[image]

I have double-checked my code multiple times. This is particularly frustrating as this is the very first exercise!

Kindly point out what I am missing here!

Find below my code:

```
const brain = require('brain.js');

var net = new brain.NeuralNetwork();

net.train([
  { input: [0, 0], output: [0] },
  { input: [0, 1], output: [1] },
  { input: [1, 0], output: [1] },
  { input: [1, 1], output: [0] },
]);

var output = net.run([1, 0]); // [0.987]

console.log(output);
```

I am running Nodejs version `v14.17.4`

Comment: Same issue here...

Comment: @Matthew I cant believe it. This is the first time I've posted something on StackOverflow and failed to get any help from the community.
Kindly let me know when you manage to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out its just documented incorrectly.

In reality the export from brain.js is this:

```js
{
  brain: { ...brain class },
  default: { ...brain class again }
}
```

So in order to get it working properly, you should do

```js
const brain = require('brain.js').brain // access to nested object
const net = new brain.NeuralNetwork()
```